# Proxima Centauri radio signal

Tags: astronomy, radio-frequency, exoplanets

I have recently seen [an article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/ericmack/2020/12/20/alien-hunting-astronomers-investigate-a-signal-from-nearby-proxima-centauri/?sh=54724ef47032) about an unusual radio signal coming from Proxima Centauri region.
I understand there is a debate around the nature of this signal.
My question is related to this paragraph:

> “The very narrow frequency of the signal (982 MHz) suggests a technological source, but that particular band of the spectrum isn’t one usually associated with human transmissions, satellites or other spacecraft.”

1. Why do they say 982 MHZ is a technological source?
2. How is it relevant for a potential alien transmission, the fact that this band is not what humans use for satellites, spacecrafts..etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the following Scientific American article on this subject:

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/alien-hunters-discover-mysterious-signal-from-proxima-centauri/

From that article, it appears that this signal has a very narrow bandwidth and that is the reason it is unlikely a natural source:

*“We don’t know of any natural way to compress electromagnetic energy into a single bin in frequency” such as this one, [Andrew] Siemion says. Perhaps, he says, some as-yet-unknown exotic quirk of plasma physics could be a natural explanation for the tantalizingly concentrated radio waves. But “for the moment, the only source that we know of is technological.”*

Combine this statement that a technological source cannot be ruled out with the fact that this is not a band used by technology produced by humans on Earth, and you have the possibility that it is of alien origin.

As stated in the article, much more work to be done here though.